# Get the enconding of a char column through SQL query in db2

Tags: db2

How do I get the encoding of a char column in db2 through a query? I'm using Db2 i 7.2. Basically, I need to check if the enconding of a char column is "for bit data".

Answer (score 0):

`FOR BIT DATA` is not an *encoding*, it is an attribute of character data types that have *no encoding*.

Each column data type and, for character types, encoding can be found in the catalog view `QSYS2.SYSCOLUMNS` -- columns `DATA_TYPE` and `CCSID` respectively. I guess you'll be looking for `'BINARY'` and `'VARBIN'` values.

More information [in the manual](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzcatsyscol.htm?lang=en).